# Need to add mysql query in cron job

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I need to add a mysql query in a cron job. Tried some suggestions from here but not able to do.

My query:

```
mysql -u root -pitvitv -e "use tvbsadmin; show full processlist;"> /mydirectory/processlist_auto.txt.
```

Tried to write a script as below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root -pitvitv -e "use tvbsadmin; show full processlist;"> /seachange/processlist_auto.txt
```

And then added in cron job as:

```
05 * * * * root /mydirectory/processlist.sh
```

please correct me if i am trying something wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have an actual error?

Comment: No, whenever i run the query it gives output. problem is iam unable to add it in cron. i am missing something for sure. But couldn't point out.

Comment: how do you know you haven't added to cron? How DID you add it to cron?

Comment: i guess this should do: 05 * * * * root /mydirectory/processlist.sh

Comment: How did you add this to cron? What is the output in your cron log file?

Comment: i have opened the crontab file and added the above line and  closed it. i have referred the link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the MySQL queries in the script and included it in crontab.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date >> /seachange/unassigned_count.txt)
mysql -D tvbsadmin -u root -pitvitv -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eam_package WHERE STATUS IN (1,3);" >> /seachange/unassigned_count.txt
echo $(date >> /seachange/processlist_May07.txt)
mysql -u root -pitvitv -e "SELECT TIME,INFO FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE INFO !='NULL';" >> /seachange/processlist_May07.txt
```

Cron entry:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /seachange && sh Mysql_output.sh
```

Cron log o/p:

> May  7 15:30:01 verzcore1 crond[20978]: (root) CMD (cd /seachange &&
>   sh Mysql_output.sh)

It is working fine!